# XCode Custom Keyboard Cannot Connect Outlets

Tags: xcode, swift, keyboard, swift2, xcode7

I'm creating a custom keyboard using Swift 2.0 and cannot seem to connect any outlets between my KeyboardView.xib file and KeyboardViewController.swift.

Instead of CTRL-dragging the scrollview in my keyboard view file, I also tried typing in the outlet in my .swift file:

```
    @IBOutlet var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
```

to create an outlet (which it did), but when I tried to CTRL-drag that outlet to connect it to the scrollview in KeyboardView.xib, the blue line would not connect.

All in all, my goal is to create a scroll view in my custom keyboard (similar to the new Emoji IOS keyboard). If anyone has any tips on how to best create this, please let me know as well.

I'm a noob, so any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the custom class of `KeyboardView.xib` to this swift file?

Example:

[image]

Comment: I had not -- I knew it was something obvious. Thank you SO much!!